# Is it possible to get the owner (uid) of a page

Tags: facebook-fql

I need to know the uid of the owner of certain pages.
But these pages are not the ones I managed.

For example if I want to know the uid of this page vía FQL:
SELECT uid FROM page_admin WHERE page_id=188713234485099

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance